# Transparent background image (Drawable) on KitKat 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, transparent, alpha-transparency

I am to set transparent drawable image on backgrount of layout, it is working fine on Lollipop+ devices, But background does not appear on Pre-Lollipop devices.
Here is my `.xml` code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/emptyWorkFlowImage">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_empty_sequence_list"
        android:id="@+id/ivEmptyLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my transparent drawable image.
[image]

Image has some text and one arrow..

Comment: can you add screenshot so we can understand what exactly happening?

Comment: It does not show any thing on background. I have update my question with drawable, which I am using for background.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it programmatically.

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_your_image);
```